# Multi-schema Postgres on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm extending an existing Rails app, and I have to add multi-tenant support to it. I've done some reading, and seeing how this app is going to be hosted on Heroku, I thought I could take advantage of Postgres' multi-schema functionality.

I've read that there seems to be some performance issues with backups when multiple schemas are in use. This information I felt was a bit outdated. Does anyone know if this is still the case?

Also, are there any other performance issues, or caveats I should take into consideration?

I've already thought about adding a field to every table so I can use a single schema, and have that field reference to the tenants table, but given the time windows multiple schemas seem the best solution.

Answer (score 11):

I use postgres schemas for a multi-tenancy site based on some work by Ryan Bigg and the Apartment gem.

---

https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails

https://github.com/influitive/apartment

---

I find that having seperate schemas for each client an elegant solution which provides a higher degree of data segregation.  Personally I find the performance improves because Postgres can simply return all results from a table without have to filter to an 'owner_id'.

I also think it makes for simpler migrations and allows you to adjust individual customer data without making global changes.  For example you can add columns to specific customers schemas and use feature flags to enable custom features.

My main argument relating to performance would be that backup is a periodic process, whereas customer table scoping would be on every access.  On that basis, I would take any performance hit on backup over slowing down the customer experience.

Comment: Interesting to hear. I got the same book. Still half way thorough. But I didn't see any keywords in a reverse proxy config. Is it possible to use the **subdomain** approach in Heroku? What config do we need to do?